# Ionic cordova resources no responding

Tags: ionic2, ionic-cli

it keep this state for about an hour and that's definitely not normal. anyone's help are appreciated. thanks
[image]

Comment: maybe it just because of my network speed? when i execute the command again. it just up to 17 / 18. sadly. it jammed again.

Comment: On which platform?

Comment: on windows 10(ionic-cli: 3.10.1). and after another hour. it did finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mostly because of my **image size**. which is 3M. and after i compress it to 200K. it finished less then 2 minutes.

hopefully it did some help to you.